# Magento 2 cart rule conditions and action to exclude specific product using sku

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, action, condition

I have added cart rule and its working properly, I need to exclude specific product from cart rule and others to go with cart rule.

***EX: sku1 need to exclude from cart rule***.

> 1.Only "sku1" in the cart - No need to add cart rule.
>
> 2.Other products only (no sku1 product) - Need to add cart rule
>
> 3.Sku1 and other products - Add cart rule only to other products price value, exclude sku1.

please give some ideas to handle condition and action options.

Answer (score 1):

Use below process for this

Make sku as Use for Promo Rule Conditions from attribute

Now add actions as below in cart price rule under "Actions" Section

[image]

It works for you. please accept answer if it works for you :-)

Comment: thanks @Hitesh Agrawal. this is fine. But if I added Other products + SKU1, discount rate goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add conditions at 2 places.

Make SKU as Use for Promo Rule Conditions from attribute.

1. Now add actions as below in the cart price rule under the "Actions" Section

[image]

and secondly, you also need to add a condition in section mentioned below:

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).

[image]

It will definitely fulfill your requirement.

Thanks